# hibernate6 throw exception 'scale has no meaning for floating point numbers'

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Before, I was used hibernate 5.x everything is ok.

After update hibernate to 6.1.7 the project got exception.

I'm using springboot 3.0.5 and cofing the following properties to auto generate tables on mysql 8.0 :

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

My Entity like :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TEST")
public class TPriceRange implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "price", precision = 5, scale = 2)
    private Double price;
}
```

When I start the project , the exception is :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to determine SQL type name for column 'price' of table 't_test'
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlTypeName(Column.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.StandardTableExporter.getSqlCreateStrings(StandardTableExporter.java:99)
    ... 179 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: scale has no meaning for floating point numbers
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect$SizeStrategyImpl.resolveSize(Dialect.java:3853)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$1.resolveSize(MySQLDialect.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getColumnSize(Column.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlTypeName(Column.java:248)
```

It seems that the 'scale ' can not be used, I don't know why?

Did someone can help me?

Thank you very mush!

hibernate6 scale has no meaning for floating point numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I mean, the exception is supposed to be pretty self-explanatory.

Floating point types don't have a scale (that's the exact literal meaning of "floating" point), so this mapping is not sensible:

```java
@Column(name = "price", precision = 5, scale = 2)
private Double price;
```

So just remove the text `scale = 2`.

If you wanted this monetary value to have a set precision and scale, you should use `BigDecimal` instead of `Double`, and map it to the SQL type `DECIMAL(5,2)` or `NUMERIC(5,2)`.
Just remove the text `scale=2`. For example:

```java
@Column(name = "price", precision = 5, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal price;
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I had removed precision and scale. It was very painful to remove all of this in my project. :=)

Comment: Thanks, i had the same scenario and solved by your answer.
Thumsp up.

Comment: Scale has no meaning on the java side in this case, but if you create a database from the mapping it makes a difference if its numeric(8,5) or numeric(8,5) or numeric(8,2)

Comment: I always tried to map my entities as close to the database as possible in a way that I could let hibernate create my tables - though i would never do that in prod. but with this change now how would i set precision and scale in the generated ddl? Sure, BigDecimal would solve this. But is this really the suggested way?